# Where can we find larger size Maternity Clothing?

Tags: pregnancy, clothes, mother

My partner is a UK Size 22 ([according to this](http://www.monsoon.co.uk/help/size-guide/page/sizeguide/#europeanusa) that's US size 18, European Size 48-50), and is now at the stage where she requires maternity wear. This has proven to be incredibly difficult to find in her size and above (apparently you're supposed to go one size bigger on the maternity wear).

We've found a few places that do tops, but our real issue is finding nice trousers/jeans.

I was hoping people could recommend places to go. Places that we've already tried that cater to the larger sizes have either stopped doing maternity wear or only go up to size 22, which we're worried will become too small during the later stages.

One thing I'm especially interested in is if US/Mainland European users have the same issues at size 18+ (i.e. is this a general problem) or can advise us of good places/websites to look at.

I'm asking this because we're finding it very frustrating to handle, and I'm sure other UK site visitors will be having the same problems.

Comment: While this was possibly on topic back in the early days of the site, it is not within scope now so I have closed with the price shopping reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I live in the EU (Denmark), but when it came to maternity clothes, I ordered online from US stores and had them shipped over.

I personally shopped at Lane Bryant Maternity, but I don't know that they're still in business.  I know that Motherhood.com has up to a 3X for sizes, and that should be large enough, since the front of the 3rd trimester jeans are normally an elastic 'panel' that will stretch to accomodate a growing stomach.

You could also try plusmommaternity.com

I'm normally a size 24, and I purchased a 3X pair of 3rd trimester jeans and they fit fine throughout the end of my pregnancy.

Comment: +1 fantastic! Thanks, we'll check this out. I'm going to leave this marked unanswered for a while, see if we get any more responses, but hopefully we'll find some nice stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Darwy's Answer is the one I accepted as there was plenty of choice on there, but we found a lot of those items too expensive.

One thing it encouraged us to to do was to check out eBay, where we found a seller called [Bumps and Beyond](http://myworld.ebay.co.uk/bumps_beyond/), who do far more reasonable prices.

Comment: I'm posting this here as it's clearly one of the best choices for size 22+ maternity wear, but community wiki'ing it, so I won't be gaining reputation for any upvotes. Also, I have no affiliation with the site beyond "customer".

Comment: Well depending on when your partner is due; she may or may not need a lot of clothes.  I had 2 pairs of jeans with a full panel, one with a half, and then 6 tops and 1 sweater - that was my 'maternity' wardrobe - and I think I spent about 350$ USD on it. I was due in May, so I was still 'normal sized' (for a plus sized gal) during the winter, where I could still wear all my regular winter clothes and whatnot.